# Как объявить массив лямбд

Tags: c++, массивы, c++11, лямбда-выражение

Заинтересовал такой теоретический вопрос - а как объявить массив лямбд? И можно ли это сделать в принципе? Например, объявляем массив, потом в цикле заполняем его лямбдами, например, с захватом разных параметров, или еще как... Или, скажем, `vector<...>` - как его заполнить лямбдами?

Откровенно говоря, никогда не вдавался в такие детали, `auto` хватало с головой...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться шаблоном `std::function`. Но все лямбды должны быть с одинаковой сигнатурой.

```
std::vector<std::function<int(void)>> lambdas;

lambdas.push_back([](){ return 1; });
lambdas.push_back([](){ return 2; });
/* ... */
```

Если самому сигнатуру писать лениво, то можно заставить компилятор подставлять её автоматически:

```
auto lambda1 = [](){ return 1; };
std::vector<decltype(lambda1)> lambdas;

lambdas.push_back(lambda1 );
lambdas.push_back([](){ return 2; });
```

Поскольку захват переменных не оказывает влияния на сигнатуру лямбды, то можно заполнить массив вроде бы совершенно разными лямбдами:

```
int i0, i1;

std::vector<std::function<int(void)>> lambdas;

lambdas.push_back([](){ return -1; });
lambdas.push_back([=](){ return i0 + i1; });
lambdas.push_back([i0](){ return i0; });
lambdas.push_back([&i0](){ return i0++; });
lambdas.push_back([&](){ return i0++ + i1++; });
lambdas.push_back([&i0,i1](){ return i0++ + i1; });
/* и т.д. */
```

Comment: Спасибо! А захват никак не влияет? Т.е. только типы параметров и возвращаемого значения?

Comment: @Harry Можно и с захватом. Абсолютно безразлично. Захват не влияет на сигнатуру, только на замыкание.

Comment: Этот ответ не верен. В массиве тут хранятся объекты `std::function`, а не лямбды. А код с непосредственным сохранением в векторе лямбд `std::vector<decltype(lambda1)> lambdas; lambdas.push_back([](){ return 2; });` нерабочий, так как тип второй лямбды отличается от исходной (даже несмотря на такую же сигнатуру).

Comment: Да, второй пример не скомпилируется

Answer (score 13):

Например вот так:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> funArray;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        funArray.push_back([i](int i2) {return i2 + i;});
    for(const auto& fun : funArray)
        std::cout << "Result: " << fun(5) << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Этот ответ не верен. В массиве тут хранятся объекты `std::function`, а не лямбды.

Comment: @VTT, о как, даже не верен. Ну Вам виднее, конечно.

Answer (score 7):

Объявить массив  лямбд не сложно:

```
auto lambda{[](void) -> void {}};
decltype(lambda) lambdas[3]{lambda, lambda, lambda};
::std::vector<decltype(lambda)> lambdasv;
lambdasv.emplace_back(lambda);
```

Так как каждая лямбда имеет уникальный тип (который не зависит от ее сигнатуры), то в массиве или векторе можно будет хранить только одну и ту же лямбду:

```
auto lambda2{[](void) -> void {}};
decltype(lambda) lambdas[3]{lambda, lambda2, [](void) -> void {}}; // ошибка!
lambdasv.emplace_back(lambda2); // ошибка!
lambdasv.emplace_back([](void) -> void {}); // ошибка!
```

А после инициализации значения элементов массива изменять нельзя, так как операторы присваивания запрещены (**UPD:** [до C++20](https://wg21.link/p0624)):

```
lambdas[2] = lambda; // ошибка
```

Answer (score 2):

> Можно воспользоваться шаблоном `std::function`. Но все лямбды должны быть с одинаковой сигнатурой.

А можно хранить и лямбды разных сигнатур. На помощь придёт обертка `std::any` (до С++17 `std::experimental::any`).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <experimental/any>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  std::map<std::string,std::experimental::any> Map;
  
  // заносим просто число
  Map["0"] = 0;
  std::cout << std::experimental::any_cast<int>(Map["0"]) << std::endl;
  
  // заносим лямбду первого типа
  auto LamOne = [&]()->int {return 1;};
  Map["1"] = LamOne;
  std::cout << std::experimental::any_cast<decltype(LamOne)>(Map["1"])() << std::endl;
  
  // заносим лямбду второго типа
  auto LamTwo = [&](bool i)->std::string {return (i) ? "positive":"negative";};
  Map["2"] = LamTwo;
  std::cout << std::experimental::any_cast<decltype(LamTwo)>(Map["2"])(true) << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

Код носит чисто "академический" характер :-) Ибо последующее использование массива или карты лямбд с разными сигнатурами крайне неудобное.

[Онлайн пример тут](https://ideone.com/BIp2UN).

Answer (score 2):

Лямбды с пустым списком захвата можно преобразовать в указатели на функции:

```
#include <vector>

int main() {
    auto l_1 = []()  { return 42; };
    auto l_2 = []()  { return 43; };
    auto p_1 = *[]() { return 44; };

    std::vector<int (*)()> v{l_1, l_2, p_1};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто оберни создание лямбды в функцию:

```
#include <vector>

constexpr auto make_lambda(int z) {
    return [z](int i, int j) { return i + j + z; };
}

std::vector<decltype(make_lambda(42))> v{make_lambda(1), make_lambda(2)};
```

Answer (score 1):

***NB** Приоритет за [ответом Max](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1437417/416121). Если вы считаете что мой ответ достоин плюса, сперва нажмите плюс на его ответе. Я не удаляю свой ответ, так как тут приведены полные примеры, которые могут быть практически полезными.*

Функция возвращающая лямбды может быть использована для заполнения массива:

```
#include <iostream>

auto make_add(int a) {
    return [a](int b) { return a + b; };
}

int main() {
    decltype(make_add(0)) lambdas[] = {
        make_add(41), make_add(42), make_add(43)
    };
    for (auto lambda: lambdas) {
        std::cout << lambda(1) << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion lambdas.cpp
>
> $ ./a.out
> 42
> 43
> 44
> ```

Ещё пример. Лямбды представляют линейные формы:

```
#include <iostream>

auto make_line(double k, double b) {
    return [k, b](double x) { return k * x + b; };
}

int main() {
    decltype(make_line(0, 0)) lines[] = {
        make_line(1, 0.4), make_line(2, 0.5), make_line(3, 0.6)
    };
    for (auto line: lines) {
        std::cout << line(10) << '\n';
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ g++ -std=c++14 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion lines.cpp
>
> $ ./a.out
> 10.4
> 20.5
> 30.6
> ```

Comment: Это массив функций-оберток, вызывающих лямбды, нет?

Comment: Нет. `decltype(make_add(0))` - тип самой лямбды. Вызов `lambda(1)` возвращает число. Значит `lambda` - это лямбда.

Comment: Пардон, не вызывающих, а возвращающих. Сейчас по позднему времени плохо соображается, посмотрю завтра на свежую голову...

Comment: Так, а как быть, если нужны *разные* лямба-функции (два `return`) с одинаковыми параметрами и возвратом (например, `[](int b) { return b; };` и `[](int b) { return b*b; };`)?  Всю функциональность вбивать в одну лямбду? но тогда массив и не нужен получается...

Comment: Две лямбды не будут работать. Массив всё ещё имеет смысл как хранилище различных замыканий для лямбды одного и того же типа.

Comment: Для меня было откровением что лямбду можно вернуть из функции и не получить неопределённое поведение. Теперь я знаю про лямбды больше. Благодаря вам, Harry. Спасибо!