# Массив указателей на функции

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, visual-c++

Есть ли в c++ возможность передавать массив указателей на функции в функцию?

```
void Example(double* Functions[](double, double));
```

Здесь ошибка -  "Использование массива функций не допускается".

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Конечно, есть. Как и любой другой массив. Без точного вопроса более подробно ответить не получается...

Comment: @Harry как можно(нужно) передавать по другому?

Comment: Вроде просто скобок не хватает.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтоб было понятнее, воспользуемся `typedef`:

```
typedef double (*Func)(double, double);
void Exapmple(Func f[]) { ... }
```

Например, так. Полный пример — [тут](https://ideone.com/wJWyVq).

Без `typedef` -

```
void Example(double (*f[])(double, double), double x, double y)
```

P.S. Можно использовать даже [массив лямбда-функций](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/485779/195342), кстати :)